# unable to use android phonegap facebook-connect , twitter plugins

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to android phonegap, and am trying to integrate social media login to my android app.

But I cannot find any proper understandable docs for facebook or twitter login to android app. I have tried to use the `facebook-connect` and twitter plugin posted in github, but I can't understand how to use this the steps mentioned in the read me file is confusing as it gives only a vague idea, most if the code is deprecated in android.

Someone please help me 
P.S : I am using phonegap 2.9.0

Comment: You haven't did the research properly. Why dont you start from the official developers site? http://developers.facebook.com

Comment: I tried both the facebook and phonegap developers sites but none docs were understandable and that too I am using phonegap 2.9.0 and all most all the references  are for old versions of phonegap. The read me file in the github repository for android phonegap facebook connect is not at all understandable:- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin . In Step 3.)"Add a new com.facebook.LoginActivity activity to your app to handle Facebook Login.". is vague.It does not say how to handle facebook login in phonegap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi a sample project of `facebook-connect` is there  is icenium...Try looking into that..

http://www.icenium.com/.. Create an account and in its sample projects you will able to get the whole code of `facebook-connect`

Comment: one thing I forgot to ask, i tried twitter and linkedin the same way but the result was disappointing. Twitter plugin provided by android phonegap github repository is depricated. is it possible to handle twitter and linkedin login like facebook login. can i get any working plugins.

Comment: did u got your solution??

Comment: I tried a lot, but did not get any solution.